Capture the Parent child relation between layers
class Model(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, instance_size=15, X_size=5, Uncern_size=5):

    super(MyModel, self).__init__()

    self.embedding_instance = nn.Linear(instance_size, 8)
    self.embedding_X = nn.Linear(X_size, 3)
    self.embedding_uncern = nn.Linear(Uncern_size, 3)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(14, 5)  
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5, 1)
    

def forward(self, instance, X, uncern):
    
    instance_embed = torch.relu(self.embedding_instance(instance))
    X_embed = torch.relu(self.embedding_X(X))
    uncern_embed = torch.relu(self.embedding_uncern(uncern))
    
    concatenated = torch.cat((instance_embed, X_embed, uncern_embed), dim=1)
    
    output = torch.relu(self.fc1(concatenated))
    output = self.fc2(output)

    return output

model =Model()

The function I am trying to write should return the child-parent (key-value) relation as follows.
{ input_layers => [“instance”, “X”, “Uncern”],
  hidden_layers => {“embedding_inst” => [“instance”],
                    “embedding_X” => [“X”],
                    “embedding_Uncern”=> [“Uncern”],
                    “fc1” => [“embedding_inst”, “embedding_X”, “embedding_Uncern”]},
  output_layers => {“fc2” => [“fc1”])}
}

I am trying to use the model.fc1.named_children() method, but it returns a empty list. I was hoping to get the layer name “fc2” as an output so that I could write a function that produced the desired dict. Is there a way I could do it?

fc1 doesn't have any children and it has no way of knowing how the incoming tensor was formed (here with a three tensor concatenation). It only expects a tensor of a specific shape, that's all. One solution would be to wrap the nn.Linear with a custom layer. Is that what you would like to have?

@Ivan, thanks for the clarification on the .children method. Is there a way I could extract the DAG of just the forward pass? I didn't understand the custom layer part you mentioned.

It's not exactly what you want, but the torchviz library can render the computational graph of your forward pass

@Rohit922, a preview of what that would yield: here
